# Normalization and Breaking down tables for InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, performance, normalization, query-performance

I'm designing a web application, something small but deals with lots of read and inserts.
Let's say 60% read and 40% writes. My storage engine is InnoDB on MySQL. I have a table
called User which has a bunch of stuff in it. I broke it down into smaller tables such as
address table and bio table. Here is an example :

Original table

```
User table
----------
user_id   PK
user_email
user_pass
user_dob
user_gender
user_country
user_state
user_city
```

After breaking it down

```
User table
----------
user_id   PK
user_email
user_pass

Bio Table
----------
user_dob
user_gender

Address Table
-------------
user_country
user_state
user_city
```

So do you guys think, having smaller table but several of them is better for a high
traffic database or should I keep them all in one table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I see it, it's better to have it separate, that's [relational database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database)

If N User can have 1 address, the design should be:

[image]

if N user can have M address (user with more address, and an address for multiples user), should be:
[image]

For both design, the table USER, Column ID is the Primary key of that table, and User_id is just a FK.
In the second design, Table Address, column ID, it's another PK, that make a relation N:M with user, and create "user_has_table" with 2 foreign keys (user PK and address PK).